# See active sidekiq processes from inside rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

**Question:**

Is there a way to see all of the running sidekiq instances for a single rails app? I want to know if there is another deployed instance with a sidekiq process picking up my jobs.

**Backstory:**

I'm in a situation where I need to know if another sidekiq process (on a new instance) has started picking up jobs so that I can enable some sort of pause mechanism to keep my current sidekiq process from doing anything

This has to do with blue-green deployment, and the problem is that jobs are at times being processed by the old workers during deployment while both machines are active.

Answer (score 0):

This is the piece I was missing, the 'remote control' feature of sidekiq.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#processes